# Unable to import / deploy business network to Composer Playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Using the guide on https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html

The shell script has downloaded Hyperledger Composer 0.8.0 and Fabric V1 Beta docker images.

When using the Playground on my browser I am unable to deploy/import any sample business network (tried marbles network).

With the error:

```
t: line 33 column 1, to line 36 column 2. Class TradeMarble is not declared as abstract. It must define an identifying field.
```

[Error on Composer Playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ1vn.png)

I know there is a newer version of Composer (0.8.1; with 0.9.0 coming really soon) and Fabric V1 RC1. Do I need to update Composer and Fabric runtime/images?

Answer (score 2):

We are in the process of updating the samples to support Composer v0.9. When v0.9 is released the online Composer Playground will be updated and you will be able to import samples again.

Sorry for the inconvenience!